# Golden Apple Archipelago, are you under the same sky?

Tags: genshin-impact

> *In Teyvat, the stars in the sky will always have a place for you*

Since the game was released last year, Travelers have been looking at the sky. Soon, someone noticed *something* floating up there, a constant presence that will accompany you everywhere, every time.

[image]

An island floating in the sky. Some say it is Celestia, some say it is the proof of the sky being fake. No mater what they say, the island still linger there, a constant presence. Or so it seems...

The Golden Apple Archipelago. A place lost in a dense fog, the first time you settle foot there you barely can see the sky, let alone something flying there.

[image]

But later, when the mist leaves place to the brightness of the sun, when the sky finally greets you again with its blue... something... seems missing.

[image]

The question is simple:
Did anyone manage to catch a glimpse of the floating ruins anywhere in the Archipelago? And does the game provide any form of clue/lore as to **why** it shouldn't be  visible from there? While the exact position of the island isn't know, it should be "close enough" to Mondstadt for Venti to know about and Dvalin to fly too in reasonable time and the ruins are even visible from Liyue probably even from Inazuma...

---

**UPDATE:**
Apparently, in game lore confirms that the Archipelago is close enough to Mondstadt that a cataclysm managed to blast an entire mountain and make it fall there.

> Albedo: "This whole island is a chunk of Mondstadt mountain. A great force dislodged it from the mountain range and cast it into the sea. As it fell, it began to spin, and ultimately landed upside-down, hence the topography you see today."
> Albedo: "Rather interesting. Another masterwork by the Anemo Archon, Barbatos, no doubt."

"Another masterwork from Venti".... or more probably, Alice, who didn't like the current view and thought that the mountain had to go...

Comment: In the first picture, the look of the island is a bit similar to the celestia in-game though. My guess is that the golden apple archipelago might be in another side of teyvat  where celestia/floating island isn't visible or that it has some particular connection with the recent people that got ascended to celestia which is Vennessa from monstadt and Guhua from Liyue.

Comment: @AldrinDino I appreciate the comment but I am not really sure the archipelago could be that far from Mondstadt in the first place. It is true that no one knows about it there, but somehow multiple people went there in a short time and it doesn't seem like the journey took days.

Comment: that's true though